# How can we define a partial ordering on the the $\mathbb{R}$-valued $n$ by $n$ matrix vector space?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

The vector space

$$V = M_{n,n}(\mathbb{R})$$

is defined with the scalar operation: 
$$\cdot : (\mathbb{R}, V) \rightarrow V, \text{ s.t. }  a \cdot v \in V$$

and the usual axioms apply:
$$(ab \ \ +_{\mathbb{R}} \ \ cd) \cdot (x \ \ +_V \ \ y) =  (dc)\cdot y \ \ +_V \ \ (ba)\cdot x$$
$$(a\cdot x)*(b \cdot y) = (ab)\cdot (x*y) = (b \cdot x)*(a \cdot y)$$
$$1 \cdot x = I_n * x = x*I_n = x$$
$$0 \cdot x = \textbf{0}$$
where $(*, \ +_{\mathbb{R}}, \ +_V)$ refer to matrix multiplication, real addition, and matrix addition. (Usually it's safe to ignore these symbols, or drop the subscripts, when the meaning is obvious).

I want to define a notion of ordering (partially) on $V$ with the usual less-than symbol $<$.
$$ < \ \subset \ V \times V$$
and I want this symbol defined in terms of a yet-to-be-found function $\mu$.
$$\mu : V \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$$
such that:
$$\forall x, y \in V, \ \ x<y  \Leftrightarrow \mu(x) < \mu(y) $$

where the right hand $<$ is the usual less-than relationship over $\mathbb{R}$.
Note that $\mu(x) = \mu(y)$ does not necessarily imply that $x=y$, so we cannot assert the usual property that $(x < y) \text{ or } (x=y) \text { or } (y<x)$, this will not hold in my vector space $V$.

To start with, I tried laying down some assumptions about $\mu$:

$$\mu(x) = 0 \ \ \Leftrightarrow \ \ x = \textbf{0}$$
$$\mu(x*y) = \mu(x) \mu(y)$$
$$\mu(x^T) = \mu(x), \text{ where $x^T$ is the transpose of $x$}$$
$$\mu(a \cdot x) = (a)(\mu(x)), \text{ for all } a \in \mathbb{R}$$

But now I'm rather stuck. Is there a way to define such a $\mu$ function fully? Or are my axioms inconsistent?

Thanks
~Greg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such function $\mu$ satisfying the first and the second properties at the same time.

Assume that such a function exists. It suffices to take $x,y\in V\setminus \left\{ \textbf{0} \right\} $ such that $x*y=\textbf{0}$, and applying $\mu$ to both sides to get $\ \mu (x*y)=0 \iff \mu(x)\mu(y)=0 \iff \mu(x)=0 \ \vee \ \mu(y)=0 \iff x=\textbf{0} \ \vee \ y=\textbf{0} $ which is a contradiction.

Comment: Excellent thank you! I forgot about this trick because when I did ring-theory, we limited the scope of the course to integral domains where $(x*y = 0) \ \Rightarrow \ ((x=0) \lor (y=0))$. Thanks for your quick and clear answer.